# Preserve toggle state using jQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery Toggle with Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523189/jquery-toggle-with-cookie)

Am having a simple toggle, but the toggle always resets when the page refreshes, so I want to preserve its state by setting a cookie but am not having much Idea how should I do it...

Any idea how do I preserve the state of toggle?

http://jsfiddle.net/Qyufx/

```
<div class="question_trigger">
   <p>Hi</p>
</div>
<div class="toggle_container">
   <div class="block">Hello</div>
</div>


jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".toggle_container").hide();
        jQuery("div.question_trigger").click(function(){
        jQuery(this).toggleClass("active").next().toggle("slow");
    });
});​
```

​

Comment: do you only need to preserve the state on reload or if one came back after being somewhere else?

Comment: I need to preserve the state till the user is logged in :)

Comment: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: @Joddy can you provide me with a fiddle integrating that plugin?

Comment: @Barmar what do you understand from that answer cuz I cannot

Comment: I would use a PHP session variable updated through AJAX instead of cookie. Tell me if you need an example

Comment: @sdespont you cannot do that, PHP cannot change the cookie value unless and until the page is refreshed

Comment: @sdespont sure I would like to see that

Comment: @RandomGuy : No need cookie with my solution

Comment: @sdespont so you'll be preserving the state in the database? if it's so, I have no problem, just let me know the procedure, this is important for me

Comment: @sdespont But PHP doesn't know that you changed the state of the toggle until you submit the form.

Comment: The answer in the linked question seems pretty simple to me. When the page is loaded it toggles the container based on the value in the cookie. And whenever you click on the toggle button it saves the current state in the cookie.

Comment: @Barmar can you modify my fiddle and show?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution using cookie:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".toggle_container").toggle($.cookie('showTop') != 'collapsed');
    jQuery("div.question_trigger").click(function() {
        jQuery(this).toggleClass("active").next().toggle();
        var new_value = $(".toggle_container").is(":visible") ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed';
        $.cookie('showTop', new_value);
    });
});​
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/Qyufx/14/)

Comment: You are just awesome man thank you very very much, I really appreciate it..

Answer (score 1):

Basic solution using PHP session variable to store the toggle state

Step 1 : Set the container visible or not durring page loading by checking the PHP session variable value :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    if(<?php echo (isset($_SESSION['userId']['toggleState'] && $_SESSION['userId']['toggleState'] === FALSE) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>)
        $('.toggle_container').hide();
});
```

Step 2 : Add the script to update the PHP session variable

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery(".toggle_container").hide();

        jQuery("div.question_trigger").click(function(){
            jQuery(this).toggleClass("active").next().toggle("slow");

            var data = ($(this).is(":visible")) ? 'true' : 'false';
            $.ajax({
              url: 'ajax/update.php',
              method : 'post',
              data : {data : data},
              success: function(data) {
                  console.log('data updated');
              },
              error: function (request, status, error) {
                  alert(request.responseText);
              }
            });
        });
});​
```

Step 3 : implement ajax/update.php code (use the real userId database value)

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['userId']['toggleState'] = (isset($_POST['data']) && $_POST['data'] === 'true') ? true : false;
?>
```