# Having trouble implementing cookie save state to JQuery toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I've been coming up with a JQuery toggle with the help of Nicolas R that saves the state of the toggle using a cookie but am currently having trouble implementing it as it pulls in the same title for for all the buttons once activated.

Please find below:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" id="slide1">Slide Toggle +</a>
    <div id="slide1panel" style="display:none; background-color:#4CF;width:100px;height:200px;"></div>
</div>

<div>
    <a href="#" id="slide2">Slide Toggle +</a>
    <div id="slide2panel" style="display:none; background-color:#4CF;width:100px;height:200px;"></div>
</div>
```

JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // check the cookies when the page loads
    // 1st panel
    if ($.cookie('currentToggleslide1panel') === 'visible') {
        togglePanel($('#slide1panel'), $('#slide1'), true, 0);
    }
    // 2nd panel
     if ($.cookie('currentToggleslide2panel') === 'visible') {
        togglePanel($('#slide2panel'), $('#slide2'), true, 0);
    }    

    //handle the clicking of the show/hide toggle button of the 1st panel
    $('#slide1').click(function() {
        //toggle the panel as required, base on current state
        if ($('#slide1').text() === "Slide Toggle +") {
            togglePanel($('#slide1panel'), $('#slide1'), true, 'slow');
        }
        else {
            togglePanel($('#slide1panel'), $('#slide1'), false, 'slow');
        }
    });

     //handle the clicking of the show/hide toggle button of the 2nd panel
    $('#slide2').click(function() {
        //toggle the panel as required, base on current state
        if ($('#slide2').text() === "Slide Toggle +") {
            togglePanel($('#slide2panel'), $('#slide2'), true, 'slow');
        }
        else {
            togglePanel($('#slide2panel'), $('#slide2'), false, 'slow');
        }
    });
});

function togglePanel(panel, button, show, toggleSpeed) {
    if(toggleSpeed > 0 || toggleSpeed === 'slow' || toggleSpeed === 'fast') {
        panel.slideToggle(toggleSpeed);
    } else {
        panel.toggle();
    }

    if (show) {
        // Set a cookie containing the panel name
        $.cookie('currentToggle' + panel.attr('id'), 'visible', { path: '/' });
        button.text('Slide Toggle -');
    } else {
        // Set a cookie containing the panel name
        $.cookie('currentToggle' + panel.attr('id'), 'hidden', { path: '/' });
        button.text('Slide Toggle +');
    }
}
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xVa7e/1/)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cozmoz,

I updated the referenced cookie script in your JS Fiddle (see external resources): it seems to work now. When I first tried the cookie was causing a bug.
The text is changing independtly, can you check if you have a bug in the fiddle?

EDIT: new response: the text are different between the panels, in this sample I use the current text and replace the last character by a plus/minus symbol

http://jsfiddle.net/xVa7e/6/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // check the cookies when the page loads
    // 1st panel
    if ($.cookie('currentToggleslide1panel') === 'visible') {
        togglePanel($('#slide1panel'), $('#slide1'), 0);
    }
    // 2nd panel
     if ($.cookie('currentToggleslide2panel') === 'visible') {
        togglePanel($('#slide2panel'), $('#slide2'), 0);
    }    

    //handle the clicking of the show/hide toggle button of the 1st panel
    $('#slide1').click(function() {
        //toggle the panel as required
        togglePanel($('#slide1panel'), $('#slide1'), 'slow');
    });

     //handle the clicking of the show/hide toggle button of the 2nd panel
    $('#slide2').click(function() {
        //toggle the panel as required
        togglePanel($('#slide2panel'), $('#slide2'), 'slow');
    });
});

function togglePanel(panel, button, toggleSpeed) {
    var panelPreviousStateVisible = panel.is(':visible');
    // Toggle the div
    if (toggleSpeed > 0 || toggleSpeed === 'slow' || toggleSpeed === 'fast') {
        panel.slideToggle(toggleSpeed);
    } else {
        panel.toggle();
    }

    // Once toggled, set the cookie and the text
    if (!panelPreviousStateVisible) { 
        $.cookie('currentToggle' + panel.attr('id'), 'visible', { path: '/' });
        // Set the text by removing the last char and add a minus symbol
        button.text(button.text().slice(0,-1) + "-");
    } else {
         $.cookie('currentToggle' + panel.attr('id'), 'hidden', { path: '/' });
        // Set the text by removing the last char and add a plus symbol
        button.text(button.text().slice(0,-1) + "+");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean updating the external resource in the fiddle to another copy of the cookie? I'm not sure if there is a bug in the code inside the Fiddle. To be fair it's mostly your code. How are you getting it to update independently? Do you have a copy of the changes you made? Much appreciated.

Comment: I changed the referenced yes, the referenced file was not mine it is a plugin of the web.
The new source came from http://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery-cookie

No change to code because I did not got the problem

Comment: The original sample was: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/master/jquery.cookie.js

In fact, files are identical, but I did not understand why jsfiddle was not working anymore with the 1st one

Comment: Okay thanks, would you mind uploading a fiddle using categories with different names, I would really like to see the way you go about implementing this! :-)

Comment: Sorry Cozmoz I don't understand your last point: what should I implement? Which categories are you talking about?

Comment: I mean the text you have managed to get to change independently.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56385/discussion-between-nicolas-r-and-cozmoz).

Comment: Hi Nicolas, did you see my last comment :-)

Comment: New update ;) you can continue in the chat if you need more things

Comment: Just letting you know I've updated the chat, I'm having a little trouble implementing the script into the CMS.

Comment: Hi Nic, have you had a chance to look at the file I sent you?

Comment: I added comments in the chat and I also have a working version.
Will you also mark the answer as valid?

Comment: Hi Nicolas, I have sent you another message in chat, I will mark the answer as valid once implemented :-).

Comment: Check the chat. (and that's a shame that there are no notifications from the chat, because we are spamming comments!)

Comment: Any news for the implementation?

Comment: Sorry, not yet. Been working on other things, will look at it over the weekend, thanks. :-)