# How to store the state of an input on a website?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, python, html

I created a webUI to control a relay board with a raspberry pi.

When a button is pressed I access the [relais.php](https://github.com/m3taas/SmartOutlet/blob/master/html/relais.php) with an AJAX request. The relais.php sends the corresponding commands to a python script from where the relays are controlled.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="IN1" onclick="in1()">
  </label>
</body>

<script>
  function in1() {
    var x = document.getElementById("IN1").checked;
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "relais.php?dir=IN1=" + x, true);
    xhttp.send();
    var out1 = x; }
</script>
</html>
```

**The problem is the page gets reloaded the buttons are reset to the "unchecked" state. How could I store the states of the inputs on the webserver?** The result would be that I could access the webUI from another device and the buttons would be "remembered" every time I reload.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to keep consistency across pages (that I can think of off the top of my head).

1. You need to store the state in a database and/or in a server session.
2. Otherwise you can store it within a cookie, and get the cookie contents, but cookies can be deleted and edited, so it might not be the best solution.

### Example PHP:

```php
<?php

// Set the header
header("Content-Type: text/json");

/* 
 * Create a Mysql connection with PDO
 * http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php 
 */

// Prepare a query
$sth = $dbh->prepare("select col1, col2, col3 from fruit where user_id = ? limit 1");

// Execute the query, and replace the `?` with the value of `$_GET['key']`
$sth->execute([$_GET['key']]);

// Get the row
$reslut = $sth->fetch();

// print the result to the page
echo json_encode($reslut);
```

### Example jQuery ajax:

```
// Make a request to the php file with the key `123456`.
// This could be a user id, hash or whatever you want it to be
// as long as it is in the database.
// this example is using it as a user id.
$.get('/path/to/phpfile.php?key=123456', result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: OP mentions the state persisting across multiple devices, ruling out cookies and sessions.

Comment: It wouldn't rule out database and session like mentioned in my first option.

Comment: Ok. Can i do a request to a database directly in Javascript or do i need to use php? (I know that JS is client-sided but is there a way of doing it in JS?)

Comment: You can make an ajax request, and the server code, `php`, `python`, or whatever server language you are using can then return json that your javascript can then handle.

Comment: Are there examples of such case of use where i could get more information. I just fount [this](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_intro.asp) but it should be doable.

Comment: @nudelkopf I have created an example

Answer (score 0):

Q: How could i make the webbrowser know which buttons are in the "checked" state and which are "unchecked" every time i load the website?

A: If you want to "save state" with respect to a particular web browser, use cookies.

If you just want to "save state", you'll need some kind of "database" on the Web/PHP server.

MySQL is a good choice, but in your case *ANYTHING* would work: including something like a MongoDB noSQL database, or even a simple text file.

Personally, I would prefer a sever-side solution.  But here's an example that uses jQuery and cookies - completely browser-side:

[jQuery Toggle with Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523189/jquery-toggle-with-cookie)